# How to display and update model data in Django One-to-one relationships?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms

I have two models Place and Restaurant with one-to-one relationship. I want to use one model form Restaurantform and display place name in the form edit mode. Upon submitting the form need to update data in both model fields.

```
class Place(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

   def __str__(self):
      return "%s the place" % self.name

class Restaurant(models.Model):
   place = models.OneToOneField(
       Place,
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
       primary_key=True,
   )
   name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   def __str__(self):
      return "%s the restaurant" % self.place.name

class Restaurantform(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Restaurant
      fields = ['name', 'serves_pizza', 'Name field from Place Model?']
```

I am not sure how to display place name and process the form submission!

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry what is it that you intend to do with your RestauranForm? i mean the task you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Why to add two models if you want to update both in one? Or you may add `place` as a choice field in your `Resturant model` by adding a foriegn key instead one-on-one

Comment: Thanks! In my question, I have used Place and the Restaurant model as an example. But I would like to know how to achieve loading and editing data from other related models. I did similar works on Yii2, Rails, and Laravel but quite not sure how to achieve on Django! Thanks for your help. @Abrar